PIT-PD vs PIT foward looking PD
I have been looking at how the two are being thrown about loosely but I just need someone to assist me with clarity between the two. I am thinking this:

PIT PD (Point In Time Probability of Default) is based on current conditions and does not explicitly include forward-looking economic forecasts. And so from the same dataset used for computing TTC-PD (Through The Cycle or long-run average PD) if I compute yearly PD and even include current economic PD I get PIT-PD. This PD is not forward-looking because it does not consider forcasted future economic outlook.

PIT Forward-Looking PD builds on PIT PD but explicitly factors in future economic scenarios, making it more proactive in anticipating changes in risk due to economic forecasts.


Are these two assertions correct?
